# Scrollbar only on top

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

I would like to set the scrollbar only above the text and remove bottom one, something like here, but using jQuery without any plugin. Can someone help?

```
function DoubleScroll(element) {
    var scrollbar= document.createElement('div');
    scrollbar.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    scrollbar.style.overflow= 'auto';
    scrollbar.style.overflowY= 'hidden';
    scrollbar.style.width= '150px';
    scrollbar.firstChild.style.width= element.scrollWidth+'px';
    scrollbar.firstChild.style.paddingTop= '1px';
    scrollbar.firstChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\xA0'));
    scrollbar.onscroll= function() {
        element.scrollLeft= scrollbar.scrollLeft;
    };
    element.onscroll= function() {
        scrollbar.scrollLeft= element.scrollLeft;
    };
    element.parentNode.insertBefore(scrollbar, element);
}
```

DoubleScroll(document.getElementById('doublescroll'));

link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nsG5w/3/

Answer (score 0):

Want something like this?

```css
div p{
  width: 1000px;
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
div{
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  transform:rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog
  The Quick Brown Fox Again Jumps Over the Lazy Dog
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want scrollbar at top, not bottom like this :)

Comment: currently there is no easy way to change the position of scrollbar, see the code snippet for possible easy way around...